# unable to produce result correctly in div php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not very sure how can I put them into words. I'm trying to display result in each div as shown in the image but unfortunately I'm only able to make it appear only in the "request for quote" div. 
May I know where have I gone wrong?

```
<?php
            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM client c, sales_card s WHERE c.id = s.client_id and emp_id_followup = '".$_SESSION["ID"]."'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
                while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                    $swimlaneID = $row2['swimlane_id'];
                }
            }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM swimlane";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo '<div id="right">'; 
                    echo '<div style="border-style:solid; height:1020px;">';
                    echo '<h2>'. $row["swimlane_name"].'</h2>';
                    echo '<ul id="'. $row["shortform"].'">';
                    if ($swimlaneID == $row["id"])
                    {
                     echo $display-> $row["shortform"]();
                    }
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }else{
            echo "no row";
            }
        ?>
```

[image: this is what I would like to achieve]

Comment: You're assigning the same ID to every new div (right), ID's should only be used once.

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers ahhh.. thanks for the enlightenment, I manage to solve it. Thanks alot!!